# How to reduce Y-Axis scale values in d3 bar chart?

Tags: d3.js

I use an bar chart. Count of y-axis is 9. So y-axis values are displaying from 0 to 9. It looks very congested. I need to reduce the values like displayed by multiplied by 2/3.

Here is my Y-axis code:

```
yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(yRange)
      //.ticks(2)
     // .tickValues(function(d,i){return totalEmpArray[i];})
      .tickSize(0)
      .orient("left")
      .tickSubdivide(true);
```

Comment: Here is a Link which would help you to understand d3 Charts Properties.

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yAxis.ticks(6)
```

or

```
yAxis.tickValues([0,2,4,6,8,10])
```

See [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#ticks).

Comment: Is it possible to use like this: .tickValues(function(d,i){return totalEmpArray[i];}) ?

Comment: Can't we make the values divided by 2/3 ?

Comment: @0991 No. What would `d` and `i` be in this case? Axis doesn't have a reference to your data.

Comment: @0991 Not necessarily. I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve or what you expect d3 to infer for you. But anyway, you can use `yAxis.ticks(6)` and d3 will do its best to match it. That's not hardcoded. Or you can generate an array with a for loop, or like this: `d3.range(0, 10, 2/3)`. You can construct an array of ticks out of some other data, like `myData.map(function() { ... })`. You can also reverse engineer how `axis.ticks(d3.time.minutes, 15)` works (see documentation link I provided), and supply a custom function. I'm not too familiar with how that last option works.